# How to finish activity do not starting the service

Tags: android

I want to start service if button hasn't been pressed and if it has then just leave my activity and also I want that if user has locked device(screen is off) then leave the activity too. I've tried this code on leaving activity if screen is off but it didn't leave the activity.Why was it happening? And what should I do to fix it?

My code:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity{
    boolean finishOrNot = false;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Log.i("Point", "yes1");
        if (getIntent().getBooleanExtra("Exit",false)==true){
           finishOrNot = true;
            Log.i("Point","yes");
        } else if(getIntent().getBooleanExtra("Exit",false)==false){
            Log.i("Point","No");
        }

        //finishOrNot = true;
        Log.i("Point", "User started app");
        final EditText editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        ImageButton imageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
        imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //startService(new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyService.class));
                String phoneNumber = editText1.getText().toString();
                Log.i("Number", phoneNumber);
                Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + phoneNumber));
                startActivity(callIntent);
                finishOrNot = true;
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    protected void onUserLeaveHint() {
        if (finishOrNot==false){
            finish();
            Log.i("Point","finishOrNot == false");
        } else{Log.i("Point","finishOrNot == true");}
        super.onUserLeaveHint();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        //startActivity(new Intent(MyActivity.this,MyActivty.class));
        Log.i("Point", "MyActivity onDestroy");
        if (finishOrNot == false) {
            startService(new Intent(MyActivity.this, MyService.class));
        }else if(finishOrNot==true) {
            Log.i("Point","fon=true");
        }
    }
}
```

And my logcat:

```
04-30 05:53:30.190  14030-14030/com.example.amadey.myapplication5 I/Point﹕ yes1
04-30 05:53:30.190  14030-14030/com.example.amadey.myapplication5 I/Point﹕ No
04-30 05:53:30.200  14030-14030/com.example.amadey.myapplication5 I/Point﹕ User started app
04-30 05:54:17.560  14030-14030/com.example.amadey.myapplication5 I/Point﹕ EndReceiver
04-30 05:54:18.300  14030-14030/com.example.amadey.myapplication5 I/Point﹕ finishOrNot == false1
04-30 05:54:18.780  14030-14030/com.example.amadey.myapplication5 I/Point﹕ yes1
04-30 05:54:18.780  14030-14030/com.example.amadey.myapplication5 I/Point﹕ yes
04-30 05:54:18.990  14030-14030/com.example.amadey.myapplication5 I/Point﹕ User started app
04-30 05:54:19.410  14030-14030/com.example.amadey.myapplication5 I/Point﹕ finishOrNot == true1
04-30 05:54:20.750  14030-14030/com.example.amadey.myapplication5 I/Point﹕ MyActivty
04-30 05:56:38.920  14030-14030/com.example.amadey.myapplication5 I/Point﹕ finishOrNot == true1
04-30 05:56:46.120  14030-14030/com.example.amadey.myapplication5 I/Point﹕ MyActivity onDestroy
04-30 05:56:47.010  14030-14030/com.example.amadey.myapplication5 I/Point﹕ MyService
```

Thank you.

Comment: Topic should be closed, please accept an answer

Answer (score 1):

You can finish the Activity with the call :

```
finish();
```

> ```
> Call this when your activity is done and should be closed.
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Try this to finish activity while screen in off mode.

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

 /**
 * Created by moorthy on 4/30/2016.
 */
public class SampleActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private BroadcastReceiver mScreenStateReceiver = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mScreenStateReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
                Log.i("Check", "Screen went OFF");
                Toast.makeText(context, "screen OFF", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                //Here you can finish you activity
                finish();
            } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {
                Log.i("Check","Screen went ON");
                Toast.makeText(context, "screen ON",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    };

}


@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    IntentFilter screenStateFilter = new IntentFilter();
    screenStateFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
    screenStateFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
    registerReceiver(mScreenStateReceiver, screenStateFilter);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This also work fine

```
moveTaskToBack(true);
finish();
```

move task to back its finish application but still in memory.